# Centralizing plugin version in (something similar to) a BOM?

Tags: maven

I am starting to use BOMs for centralizing the versions of common dependencies in my project. However, it does not seem to work for plugin versions: If I add a pluginManagement section in the BOM, the versions of the plugins declared there do not seem to affect the versions of the plugins of projects importing the BOM (Maven complains that the version has not been specified).

Why is that? What is then the "Maven" way to centralize the versions of common plugins? Should I just use a parent POM for that?

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5588

Comment: You can utilize [tiles-maven-plugin](https://github.com/repaint-io/maven-tiles) to extract plugins into separated tile(s). The plugin glues the specified tiles to the project on the fly, as if they all are the project's parents.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you use a BOM which is used by scope `import` which means only to take into account the [dependencyManagement part](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Excerpt from the docs:

> This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the
>    section. It indicates that the specified POM
>   should be replaced with the dependencies in that POM's
>    section. Since they are replaced, dependencies
>   with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the
>   transitivity of a dependency.

To define plugins you should use a parent where you define the plugin versions via pluginManagement.