# Is it possible to specify pluginManagement not in parent pom?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to setup maven plugin management for a multi-module project. I want to use `pluginManagement` section without inheritance (specify plugin versions not in parent pom). My project structure looks something like this

```
base_project
   -- pom.xml
   -- project-bom
        -- pom.xml
   -- project-a
        -- pom.xml
```

In the root pom.xml I have two modules only:

```
<modules>
    <module>project-bom</module>
    <module>project-a</module>
</modules>
```

In the project-bom pom.xml I specify `dependencyManagement` and `pluginManagement` sections with dependency and plugin versions I want to use:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.some</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.some</groupId>
                <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

In project-a pom.xml I import the project-bom pom and use dependency and plugin:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.some</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.some</groupId>
            <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm able to use dependency versions specified in the project-bom but it doesn't work for plugins. It gives me the following warning:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for <...>
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for <org.some:plugin> is missing.
```

Is it possible to specify pluginManagement not in parent pom and import it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centralizing plugin version in (something similar to) a BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475578/centralizing-plugin-version-in-something-similar-to-a-bom)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There's an [open ticket in the Maven](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5588) project to add this feature.